# Duplicate datasource on WCF Service reference

Tags: wcf, entity-framework, wcf-binding, wcf-client

[image]

I am using Entity Framework, adding WCF Service Reference at my Web client I see that there are duplicate entity objects (ComplianceEFileDetail.datasource & ComplianceEFileDetail1.datasource) shown in Reference.svcmap.

Can anyone help me this is important and need immediate solution.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there was a class created with the same name as in the database which caused this issue.

Happy Coding!!!